# TextView not allowing layer-list background drawable with bitmap in it

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, background, drawable

OK, I have looking and searched seemingly **everywhere**, and cannot find an answer to this. I think it's because I'm trying to do too much at once. I want to use the background image of the rectangle with a bitmap multiple times, with different text from the TextView.

[image: ideal]
This is an example of the bitmap (.png) file I've been trying to use:  [image: dice_one]

I want a TextView with a background of a drawable XML file that is a layer-list. See code:

box_ones xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:width="128dp" android:height="34dp">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke android:width="1dp"/>
                <solid android:color="@color/ivory"/>
                <corners android:topLeftRadius="16dp" android:topRightRadius="16dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:right="10dp">
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/dice_one" android:gravity="right|center_vertical"/>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

box_twos xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:width="@string/tBoxWidth" android:height="@string/boxHeight">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke android:width="1dp"/>
                <solid android:color="@color/ivory"/>
            </shape>
        </item>

<item android:right="10dp">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/dice_two" android:gravity="right|center_vertical"/>
</item>
```

activity_main xml:

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ones"
        android:background="@drawable/box_ones"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />
```

Strings xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="xSize">16dp</string>
    <string name="boxWidth">40dp</string>
    <string name="boxHeight">34dp</string>
    <string name="tBoxWidth">128dp</string>
</resources>
```

I have tried the above; I've tried doing a custom class that extends TextView; I've tried doing a TextView and and ImageView; I've tried doing     `android:drawableEnd`. But, each method comes up with some error that prevents me from using said method. What am I doing wrong??

`2019-01-25 14:24:29.978 4346-4346/com.dyna.ks.yscorepadv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dyna.ks.yscorepadv, PID: 4346
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dyna.ks.yscorepadv/com.dyna.ks.yscorepadv.FullscreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class TextView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class TextView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class TextView
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.dyna.ks.yscorepadv:drawable/box_twos with resource ID #0x7f06005b
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/box_twos.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f06005b
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:837)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:659)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:900)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:953)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1391)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1129)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:87)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:83)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createTextView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:177)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:102)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.dyna.ks.yscorepadv.FullscreenActivity.onCreate(FullscreenActivity.java:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-01-25 14:24:29.979 4346-4346/com.dyna.ks.yscorepadv E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 2 to dimension: type=0x3
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:730)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.updateLayerFromTypedArray(LayerDrawable.java:376)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:266)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:194)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:146)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1322)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1281)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:824)
            ... 36 more`

Comment: The stack trace says that there's a problem with `box_twos`. It looks like you've posted `box_ones`.

Comment: I just did that because it's supposed to be box_ones. I did an edit after I posted the question. Sorry!

Comment: box_twos is exactly the same as box_ones, just with `dice_two` instead of `dice_one`

Comment: Are you sure it's _exactly_ the same? I just threw that into a test project, and it works just fine for me: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V3Z7vO1Rq-PtcfJU5L8R75FnUmM14g1v/view?usp=drivesdk. The stack trace says one of the dimension measures is wrong in `box_twos`.

Comment: Now, I have a Custom Class that's extending `TextView`, but I haven't used it at all. It's just there for when I need it.

Comment: I get the same error if I use `@drawable/box_twos` as the background.

Comment: Yes, that stack trace is saying there's something wrong in `box_twos`. It doesn't say anything about `box_ones`, which is what you've posted.

Comment: I posted box_twos, and my strings.xml for you two see.

Comment: That is not exactly the same as `box_ones` – `android:width="@string/tBoxWidth" android:height="@string/boxHeight"`. You cannot use strings for dimensions.

Comment: @MikeM. And YES, you can use strings for dimensions. I do it all the time and never have a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, it an SDK issue. I had my minimum SDK at 19. In order to use `android:width` and `android:height` in the drawable, my minimum had to be 23. See image:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this didn't have anything to do with. That's just a warning saying those attributes won't be applied on older versions. If you read your stack trace, it's saying exactly as I said in my comment above; you cannot use string resources there – `Can't convert value at index 2 to dimension: type=0x3`. Type `0x3` is a string resource.